# What is the time window to deposit IRA account to handle this year tax benefit?

Tags: 401k, ira

I don't have a 401K account, but am considering opening an IRA account to save some taxes.

How long the time window is available for me to have the IRA account?

Also in my understanding in the later phase, can I do 401K catch up by depositing more money for the missed time frame.

Comment: Are you asking what's the latest date that you can contribute to an IRA and have it reduce your 2019 Federal taxes?

Comment: @RonJohn , Yes please. I might have worded incorrectly. That is exactly i am looking for.

Comment: And what is this "latter phase" you refer to?  There's a 401(k) catchup, but only for people age 50+.

Comment: Later phase is to deposit more than the limit for a year. I believe 401K allow us to do catch up for the time window which is missed to have the complete investment

Comment: Also note that IRAs are 401(k) are **different**.  To follow the "one question" rule, please edit your question to remove references to 401(k) and ask it in a different question.

Comment: "I believe 401K allow us to do catch up for the time window which is missed to have the complete investment".  That's IRA.

Comment: 401(k) contribs come from only and directly from **your paycheck** and only during the calendar year associated with that paycheck.

Comment: @RonJohn - Thank you, that is a good information.

Comment: Note that the opening can take several days, so _**open the account well before the deadline**_ - you can open it without putting money in it (or just putting a dollar in it).

Comment: Thank you @Aganju - i will start working on this by this week

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.irs.gov/retirement-plans/ira-year-end-reminders

> You can make 2019 IRA contributions until April 15, 2020.

https://www.irs.gov/retirement-plans/plan-participant-employee/retirement-topics-ira-contribution-limits

> For 2020, your total contributions to all of your traditional and Roth IRAs cannot be more than:
>
> $6,000 ($7,000 if you're age 50 or older), or your taxable compensation for the year, if your compensation was less than this dollar limit.
>
> For 2019, the limits are the same as 2020.